# Can I have json.net seiralise the type of each property?

Tags: json, serialization

I have a little object

```
public class ViewData
{
    public int HistoryId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FirstOpen { get; set; }       
}
```

I would like to turn this into a bit of json that looks like this

```
  {"SortableFields":[  
      {  
         "name":"HistoryId",
         "type":"int"
      },     
      {  
         "name":"Address",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {  
         "name":"FirstOpen",
         "type":"dateTime"
      }
]}
```

What is my best approach to this? It is within WebApi so if I could hook into the jsonFormatter then that would be great. You see though that the classes don't implement any interface, and I only want this treatment for some types. They are all in the same namespace if that helps.

Comment: do you need to be able to serialize and de-serialize to this format?

Comment: Nope just serialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my workaround ( the shortest way).

```
public static class JsonDescriptorBuilder
{
    public static string DescriptClass<T>(string header) where T : new()
    {
        var propsObj = typeof (T).GetProperties().Select(pi =>
            new
            {
                name = pi.Name,
                type = pi.PropertyType.Name // or propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName
            });

        var obj = new
        {
            ___properties = propsObj.ToArray()
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
        json = json.Replace("___properties", header);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = JsonDescriptorBuilder.DescriptClass<ViewData>("SortableFields");
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    public class ViewData
    {
        public int HistoryId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FirstOpen { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> Becarefull with `Nullable` types. Check if better for you to use
>   `propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName` instaed of
>   `propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [JsonConverter custom converter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm)

like this:

```
class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("SortableFields");
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var prop in value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("name");
            writer.WriteValue(prop.Name);
            writer.WritePropertyName("type");
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                writer.WriteValue(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType).Name);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteValue(prop.PropertyType.Name);
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

decorate your objects with this converter like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public class ViewData
{
    public int HistoryId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FirstOpen { get; set; }

}
```

this will cause your converter to fire for the classes that have this set, but normal functionality for those that do not.

EDIT:  added code to handle nullable types.